# How to get current memory page size in C#

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I need to determine the memory page size in C# without using "Kernel32.dll"

```
SYSTEM_INFO si;
GetSystemInfo(&si);
```

This is very important because the code should be cross platform and we should not have platform specific code.

Is there any .NET class which provides that data?

Comment: And how would you use the pagesize in a not-platform specific code then?

Comment: That is very simple. We are using MemoryMappedFiles , and the Views best work when they have the size of Memory Page Size. Till now, determining the Memory Page Size is the single problem.

Comment: @xanatos `Environment.SystemPageSize` is a good size to use for buffers, and the only platform-specific part to that is that different platforms will give different results, so its precisely to not be platform-specific that you'd use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`Environment.SystemPageSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.systempagesize.aspx):

> Gets the number of bytes in the operating system's memory page.

Requires .NET >= 4.0

In the remarks it is even written that:

> In Windows, this value is the dwPageSize member in the SYSTEM_INFO structure.

Comment: I've mention that we should not use SYSTEM_INFO and Windows API.

Comment: @PandichieAnton-Valentin You don't use the SYSTEM_INFO, it is a .NET method that uses it. It is implementation detail.

Comment: @PandichieAnton-Valentin Note that I think your is a XY problem: instead of thinking "what is the page size so that I can use exactly it", you could simply go big: make views of 1mb (1024*1024), with offsets that move by 1mb. The page size is surely < 1mb, so you don't have any problem.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking to solution for the problem not for the real problem. Thanks! Sencond Asnswer is even better!!!